# Simple Java 2D game - resuming the game

Tags: java, swing, 2d

I am writing a simple `Java` game and have ran into some problems while adding the pause/resume functionality.

My main game loop looks like this:

```
    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {

        while (true) {
            if (!isPaused) {
                Thread.currentThread().sleep(5);
                diamondSpawner();
                collisionDetector();
                repaint();
            } else {

            }
        }
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
    }
}
```

Additionally, I have added a `KeyListener` to the main class, which waits for the user to press 'P' to pause the game. Unfortunately, the problem is that the `KeyListener` doesn't listen to the keys while in the state of being paused. How can I make it listen?

This is the KeyListener in the main classes' constructor:

```
this.addKeyListener(new KeyAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void keyPressed(KeyEvent evt) {
                if (evt.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_P) {
                    isPaused = !isPaused;
                }
                helicopter.move(evt);
            }
        });
```

Comment: Why doesn't it listen ? Sounds like you're block the event dispatching thread, consider providing a runnable example which demonstrates you problem, everything else os guess work...

Comment: You may need to make the isPaused variable volatile or use an AtomicBoolean

Comment: @MadProgrammer thanks, volatiling the variable helped :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MadProgrammer solved my problem. Just make the variable `isPaused` volatile. 
Thanks!